# How do start CSS animation on click?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm fairly new to front-end dev so please spare me...Anyway, for [this codepen project](https://codepen.io/iteesy/pen/gJGBPY) I'm trying to get the animation where a stack of pancakes falls to the plate to activate when you click the button. It should be just an empty plate until the button is clicked.

Not sure why my JS code isn't working but if I target the pancake or stack class, the visuals still remain static.

HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="plate">
      <div class="inner-plate">
      </div>
  </div>

  <button onclick="onclick()">Good Morning!</button>

  <div class="stack">
    <div class="pancake">
      <div class="top-p"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pancake p2">
      <div class="top-p"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pancake p3">
      <div class="top-p"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pancake p4">
      <div class="top-p"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pancake p5">
      <div class="top-p"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pancake p6">
      <div class="top-p"></div>
      <div class="butter">
        <div class = "shadow"></div>
        <div class = "top-b"></div>
        <div class = "shine"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS (snippet):

```
/*------BUTTON------*/
button { 
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 25%; 
  padding: 1em 2em;
  /*CSS center element trick*/
  position: absolute;
/* Gradient */
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #FF5F6D 0%, rgba(255, 195, 113, 0.88) 100%);
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(255, 95, 109, 0.25);
  border-radius: 40px;
  /*text*/
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Montserrat, system-ui;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 15px; 
  letter-spacing: 0.14px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
}

  button:hover {
        transform: translateY(-6px); 
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #FF777C 0%, #FFC487 100%);
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 5px rgba(255, 95, 109, 0.25);
}    

.plate { 
  position: relative; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  background: #FFFFFF;
  /* Stroke */
  border: 1.25px solid #F9EADC;
  border-radius: 50%; 
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(165, 75, 75, 0.15);
}

.inner-plate { 
  position: relative;
  width: 75%; 
  height: 30px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  /* Stroke */
  border: 1.25px solid #F9EADC;
  border-radius: 50%; 
  margin: 5px auto; /*stacked "plates" without flexboxes*/ 
}

/*------ELEMENTS TO ANIMATE------*/

.pancake {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 65%;
  height: 25%;
  left: 18%;
  top: 0;
  background: #FFE68E;
  border-radius: 50%; 
  z-index: 1;
}

.top-p {
  position: absolute;
  width: 95%;
  height: 80%;
  left: 2.25%;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(222, 159, 101, 0.75) 0%, #E09148 100%);
  border-radius: 50%; 
}

.slideIn {
  -webkit-animation: slideIn 1s linear both;
  animation: slideIn 1s linear both;
}

/*------ KEYFRAMES -----*/
@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-1000px);
            transform: translateY(-1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-1000px);
            transform: translateY(-1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-1000px);
            transform: translateY(-1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $('button').onclick(function() {
    $('.pancake').addClass('slideIn');
  });
})
```

Comment: Then $ `.onclick(fn` doesn't exist, it's either .`on('click', fn` or `.click(fn`; your animation rule is already set on the .pancake class, adding the slideIn class won't have any effect. `onClick` (from HTML `onclick="` attribute) is not defined. Maybe more? Anyway, please open your [dev-tools console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) and check for all the error that get reported there.

Comment: Your code is throwing an error that `$` is not defined, have you actually added JQuery to your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of things are not right, I've fixed them and marked them with `FIX`

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    // FIX: you forgot the dot
    $('.pancake').addClass('slideIn');
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:600&display=swap');

* {
outline: none;
  /*NOTE: removing the blue outline for links and buttons is a terrible UI/UX decision for accessibility! Some folks do not have the motor skills to use a mouse and use the alternative Tab button instead. This is purely just for show and practice :-) */ 
}

body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0;
  background: #FDF6D0;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
  text-align: center; 
}

.container{
 position: absolute;
  margin-top: auto;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
  align-items: center; 
}

/*------BUTTON------*/
button { 
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 25%; 
  padding: 1em 2em;
  /*CSS center element trick*/
  position: absolute;
/* Gradient */
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #FF5F6D 0%, rgba(255, 195, 113, 0.88) 100%);
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(255, 95, 109, 0.25);
  border-radius: 40px;
  /*text*/
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Montserrat, system-ui;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 15px; 
  letter-spacing: 0.14px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
}

  button:hover {
  transform: translateY(-6px); 
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #FF777C 0%, #FFC487 100%);
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 5px rgba(255, 95, 109, 0.25);
}    

.plate { 
  position: relative; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  background: #FFFFFF;
  /* Stroke */
  border: 1.25px solid #F9EADC;
  border-radius: 50%; 
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(165, 75, 75, 0.15);
}

.inner-plate { 
  position: relative;
  width: 75%; 
  height: 30px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  /* Stroke */
  border: 1.25px solid #F9EADC;
  border-radius: 50%; 
  margin: 5px auto; /*stacked "plates" without flexboxes*/ 
}

/*------ELEMENTS TO ANIMATE------*/

.pancake {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 65%;
  height: 25%;
  left: 18%;
  top: 0;
  background: #FFE68E;
  border-radius: 50%; 
  z-index: 1;
  /*pancakes falling*/
  -webkit-animation: slideIn 1s linear both;
  animation: slideIn 1s linear both;
  
  /* FIX: Pause the animation on start */
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

/* FIX: Resume the animation when this class is added */
.slideIn {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

.top-p {
  position: absolute;
  width: 95%;
  height: 80%;
  left: 2.25%;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(222, 159, 101, 0.75) 0%, #E09148 100%);
  border-radius: 50%; 
}

.p2 {
  z-index: 2;
  top: -7%; 
  left: 18%; 
}

.p3 {
  z-index: 3;
  top: -14%; 
  left: 18%; 
}

.p4 {
  z-index: 4;
  top: -21%; 
  left: 18%; 
}

.p5 {
  z-index: 5;
  top: -28%; 
  left: 18%; 
}

.p6 {
  z-index: 6;
  top: -35%; 
  left: 18%; 
}

/*BUTTER*/
.shadow {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 8;
  top: -7%;
  left: 42%; 
  height: 30%; 
  width: 15%;
  margin: auto;
  background: #FFDE68;
  border-radius: 1px;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px rgba(202, 133, 65, 0.75);
  transform: matrix(0.74, -0.44, 0.98, 0.77, 0, 0); 
  }

.top-b {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  top: -10%;
  left: 45%; 
  height: 25%; 
  width: 10%;
  margin: auto;
  background: #FFEFB5;
  border-radius: 1px;
  transform: matrix(0.74, -0.44, 0.98, 0.77, 0, 0); 
}

.shine{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: -4%;
  left: 49%; 
  height: 7%; 
  width: 4%;
  margin: auto;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 1px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.slideIn {
  -webkit-animation: slideIn 1s linear both;
  animation: slideIn 1s linear both;
}

/*------ KEYFRAMES -----*/
@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-1000px);
            transform: translateY(-1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-1000px);
            transform: translateY(-1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-1000px);
            transform: translateY(-1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- FIX: You forgot to import the jquery in CodePen! -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="plate">
      <div class="inner-plate">
      </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- FIX: You don't need to bind function here since you've already done it in js.-->
  <button>Good Morning!</button>
  <div class="stack">
    <div class="pancake">
      <div class="top-p"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pancake p2">
      <div class="top-p"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pancake p3">
      <div class="top-p"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pancake p4">
      <div class="top-p"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pancake p5">
      <div class="top-p"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pancake p6">
      <div class="top-p"></div>
      <div class="butter">
        <div class = "shadow"></div>
        <div class = "top-b"></div>
        <div class = "shine"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

the class identifier is wrong it should be `$(".pancake")`

```
$(function() {
  $('button').onclick(function() {
    $('.pancake').addClass('slideIn');
  });
})
javascript
```

Comment: That's far from being enough.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the class identifier `.` in `$(".pancake")`

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('.pancake').addClass('slideIn');
  });
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:600&display=swap');

* {
outline: none;
  /*NOTE: removing the blue outline for links and buttons is a terrible UI/UX decision for accessibility! Some folks do not have the motor skills to use a mouse and use the alternative Tab button instead. This is purely just for show and practice :-) */ 
}

body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0;
  background: #FDF6D0;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
  text-align: center; 
}

.container{
 position: absolute;
  margin-top: auto;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
  align-items: center; 
}

/*------BUTTON------*/
button { 
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 25%; 
  padding: 1em 2em;
  /*CSS center element trick*/
  position: absolute;
/* Gradient */
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #FF5F6D 0%, rgba(255, 195, 113, 0.88) 100%);
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(255, 95, 109, 0.25);
  border-radius: 40px;
  /*text*/
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Montserrat, system-ui;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 15px; 
  letter-spacing: 0.14px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
}

  button:hover {
  transform: translateY(-6px); 
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #FF777C 0%, #FFC487 100%);
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 5px rgba(255, 95, 109, 0.25);
}    

.plate { 
  position: relative; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  background: #FFFFFF;
  /* Stroke */
  border: 1.25px solid #F9EADC;
  border-radius: 50%; 
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(165, 75, 75, 0.15);
}

.inner-plate { 
  position: relative;
  width: 75%; 
  height: 30px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  /* Stroke */
  border: 1.25px solid #F9EADC;
  border-radius: 50%; 
  margin: 5px auto; /*stacked "plates" without flexboxes*/ 
}

/*------ELEMENTS TO ANIMATE------*/

.pancake {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 65%;
  height: 25%;
  left: 18%;
  top: 0;
  background: #FFE68E;
  border-radius: 50%; 
  z-index: 1;
  /*pancakes falling*/
  -webkit-animation: slideIn 1s linear both;
  animation: slideIn 1s linear both;
}

.top-p {
  position: absolute;
  width: 95%;
  height: 80%;
  left: 2.25%;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(222, 159, 101, 0.75) 0%, #E09148 100%);
  border-radius: 50%; 
}

.p2 {
  z-index: 2;
  top: -7%; 
  left: 18%; 
}

.p3 {
  z-index: 3;
  top: -14%; 
  left: 18%; 
}

.p4 {
  z-index: 4;
  top: -21%; 
  left: 18%; 
}

.p5 {
  z-index: 5;
  top: -28%; 
  left: 18%; 
}

.p6 {
  z-index: 6;
  top: -35%; 
  left: 18%; 
}

/*BUTTER*/
.shadow {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 8;
  top: -7%;
  left: 42%; 
  height: 30%; 
  width: 15%;
  margin: auto;
  background: #FFDE68;
  border-radius: 1px;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px rgba(202, 133, 65, 0.75);
  transform: matrix(0.74, -0.44, 0.98, 0.77, 0, 0); 
  }

.top-b {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  top: -10%;
  left: 45%; 
  height: 25%; 
  width: 10%;
  margin: auto;
  background: #FFEFB5;
  border-radius: 1px;
  transform: matrix(0.74, -0.44, 0.98, 0.77, 0, 0); 
}

.shine{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: -4%;
  left: 49%; 
  height: 7%; 
  width: 4%;
  margin: auto;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 1px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.slideIn {
  -webkit-animation: slideIn 1s linear both;
  animation: slideIn 1s linear both;
}

/*------ KEYFRAMES -----*/
@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-1000px);
            transform: translateY(-1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-1000px);
            transform: translateY(-1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-1000px);
            transform: translateY(-1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="plate">
      <div class="inner-plate">
      </div>
  </div>

  <button>Good Morning!</button>

  <div class="stack">
    <div class="pancake">
      <div class="top-p"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pancake p2">
      <div class="top-p"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pancake p3">
      <div class="top-p"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pancake p4">
      <div class="top-p"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pancake p5">
      <div class="top-p"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pancake p6">
      <div class="top-p"></div>
      <div class="butter">
        <div class = "shadow"></div>
        <div class = "top-b"></div>
        <div class = "shine"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following js (i remove animation from css `.pancake` class and add `transform: translateY(-1000px);` to it)

```
function onClick() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.pancake')]
    .map(x=> x.classList.add('slideIn'));
}
```

```js
function onClick() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.pancake')].map(x=> x.classList.add('slideIn'));
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:600&display=swap');

* {
outline: none;
  /*NOTE: removing the blue outline for links and buttons is a terrible UI/UX decision for accessibility! Some folks do not have the motor skills to use a mouse and use the alternative Tab button instead. This is purely just for show and practice :-) */ 
}

body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0;
  background: #FDF6D0;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
  text-align: center; 
}

.container{
 position: absolute;
  margin-top: auto;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
  align-items: center; 
}

/*------BUTTON------*/
button { 
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 25%; 
  padding: 1em 2em;
  /*CSS center element trick*/
  position: absolute;
/* Gradient */
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #FF5F6D 0%, rgba(255, 195, 113, 0.88) 100%);
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(255, 95, 109, 0.25);
  border-radius: 40px;
  /*text*/
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Montserrat, system-ui;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 15px; 
  letter-spacing: 0.14px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
}

  button:hover {
  transform: translateY(-6px); 
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #FF777C 0%, #FFC487 100%);
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 5px rgba(255, 95, 109, 0.25);
}    

.plate { 
  position: relative; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  background: #FFFFFF;
  /* Stroke */
  border: 1.25px solid #F9EADC;
  border-radius: 50%; 
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(165, 75, 75, 0.15);
}

.inner-plate { 
  position: relative;
  width: 75%; 
  height: 30px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  /* Stroke */
  border: 1.25px solid #F9EADC;
  border-radius: 50%; 
  margin: 5px auto; /*stacked "plates" without flexboxes*/ 
}

/*------ELEMENTS TO ANIMATE------*/

.pancake {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 65%;
  height: 25%;
  left: 18%;
  top: 0;
  background: #FFE68E;
  border-radius: 50%; 
  z-index: 1;
  /*pancakes falling*/
  transform: translateY(-1000px);
}

.top-p {
  position: absolute;
  width: 95%;
  height: 80%;
  left: 2.25%;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(222, 159, 101, 0.75) 0%, #E09148 100%);
  border-radius: 50%; 
}

.p2 {
  z-index: 2;
  top: -7%; 
  left: 18%; 
}

.p3 {
  z-index: 3;
  top: -14%; 
  left: 18%; 
}

.p4 {
  z-index: 4;
  top: -21%; 
  left: 18%; 
}

.p5 {
  z-index: 5;
  top: -28%; 
  left: 18%; 
}

.p6 {
  z-index: 6;
  top: -35%; 
  left: 18%; 
}

/*BUTTER*/
.shadow {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 8;
  top: -7%;
  left: 42%; 
  height: 30%; 
  width: 15%;
  margin: auto;
  background: #FFDE68;
  border-radius: 1px;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px rgba(202, 133, 65, 0.75);
  transform: matrix(0.74, -0.44, 0.98, 0.77, 0, 0); 
  }

.top-b {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  top: -10%;
  left: 45%; 
  height: 25%; 
  width: 10%;
  margin: auto;
  background: #FFEFB5;
  border-radius: 1px;
  transform: matrix(0.74, -0.44, 0.98, 0.77, 0, 0); 
}

.shine{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: -4%;
  left: 49%; 
  height: 7%; 
  width: 4%;
  margin: auto;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 1px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.slideIn {
  -webkit-animation: slideIn 1s linear both;
  animation: slideIn 1s linear both;
}

/*------ KEYFRAMES -----*/
@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-1000px);
            transform: translateY(-1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-1000px);
            transform: translateY(-1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-1000px);
            transform: translateY(-1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="plate">
      <div class="inner-plate">
      </div>
  </div>

  <button onclick="onClick()">Good Morning!</button>

  <div class="stack">
    <div class="pancake">
      <div class="top-p"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pancake p2">
      <div class="top-p"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pancake p3">
      <div class="top-p"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pancake p4">
      <div class="top-p"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pancake p5">
      <div class="top-p"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pancake p6">
      <div class="top-p"></div>
      <div class="butter">
        <div class = "shadow"></div>
        <div class = "top-b"></div>
        <div class = "shine"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```